# How can I get a two-dimension array that stored in an one-dimension array through overload the function call operator in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading, scientific-computing

I'm writing a small scientific computational library in my free time. And I found some people said that store a two dimension array in an one dimension array is faster and you can do it by overloading the function-all operator. But I don't know how to deal with it.

Now I think the function array should do that:

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int M=10;
    int N=10;
    double x[M*N];
    cout<<x(m,n)<<endl;//print the m*N+n element of x
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do with it? Or anywhere said it.I don't see it in stackoverflow....

That the x[m*N+n] is useful for two-dimension condition. But if I have four dimension, it will be x[m*A+n*B+p*C+l*D],every time I use it, I will write a long paragraph...

Comment: The correct spelling is: **dimension**

Comment: The correct array access is `x[m*N + n]`

Comment: But if I have more dimension,it will be troublesome. Can I just through overload the function-call operator?@paddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I shall admit that you want to write a scientific computing library and that (low level) optimization will matter. It is the only reason for me not to just say: do not worry with low level arrays and only use vectors of vectors [of vectors...]

But **VLA arrays are not a C++ thing**. It is a (documented) gcc extension, also supported by Clang, but other compilers will not correctly compile `double x[M*N];`, and only reserve a 0 bytes array unless `M` and `N` are compile time constants (`constexpr`).

And even for a scientific library, the overhead of a clean `x[i][j]` over `x[i*M + j]` is insignificant. Unless you can prove through profiling that it is both required and efficient do not go that way.

That being said the idiom `x(i,j)` can be useful if you have to deal with dynamic sized multi-dimensional arrays. I once tried to build a generic library for it using the standard `[]` notation and it lead to a [nightmare](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197595/146901).

You will need:

- a class to host a dynamic sized array for the proper dimensions (you could use a template based of the dimensions number)
- a ctor with the size along all the dimensions that will allocate the underlying 1-D array - I would advise to use a vector unless you want to explicitely handle the corner cases of copy/move construction/assignment (rule of 5)
- an implementation of `operator()(int i, int j, ...)` with the correct number of dimensions that just returns (for dimensions K, L, M, N, and coordinates i, j, k , l):

  ```
    x[l + K * (k + L * (j + M * i))]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? The class Matrix1D has a 1D vector, but emulates a 2D matrix, and allows you to use the ()-operator to access it.

You can extend this to as many dimensions as you want by modifying the operator(...) and set(...) functions.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix1D {
 private:
  std::vector<double> x;
  int N;

 public:
  Matrix1D(int m, int n) {
    this->x = std::vector<double>(m * n);
    this->N = n;
  }

  double operator()(int m, int n) { return this->x[m * this->N + n]; }

  void set(int m, int n, double v) { this->x[m * this->N + n] = v; }
};

int main() {
  Matrix1D c1(5, 5);
  c1.set(3, 2, 1);
  std::cout << c1(3, 2) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ operators must be class members. Therefore, in order to provide a function call overload, you firstly need to create a custom class for your array.

```
class oneDimArray {
    private:
       unsigned int lines;
       unsigned int columns;

       // You can replace the number with the maxim size of array desired
       // be it another number or integer constant.
       double x[100]{0};
     
    public:
       
       // Overloading the class constructor to accept 2D Arrays
       oneDimArray(double [][100] matrix) {
           
           // Getting the number of lines and columns
           lines = sizeof matrix / sizeof matrix[0];
           columns = sizeof[0] matrix / sizeof(double);

           // Setting the elements
           for(unsigned i = 0; i < lines*columns; i++) {
              x[i] = matrix[i / columns][i % columns];
           }
       }

       // Finally overloading the function call operator
       double operator() (unsigned int line, unsigned int column) {
           return x[line * lines + column];
       }
};
```

After this, all you have to do is create an object of that class ( your actual array ) and initialize it:

```
oneDimArray myArray = oneDimArray( someMatrix );

// Using the overloaded operator to access elements
myArray(1, 2);
```

The following can be extended to any type of array. Furthermore, if you provide an overload to the input ( >> ) operator, you will be able to read it directly.

Comment: Your answer is the same as the already given answer. Please consider upvoting instead of given the same answer twice.